# directory creation and shifting in batch script

Tags: batch-file, jad

I have three subfolders: the folder `GHI` is inside `DEF` which is inside `ABC`. Each folder has a single class file (`xyz.class`). This means a directory structure like:

```
ABC/
    XYZ.class
    DEF/
        XYZ.class
        GHI/
            XYZ.class
```

The three `XYZ.class` files are not similar but share the same name.

I tried a script which uses JAD to decompile all the `xyz.class`es in the `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI` folders and save the decompiled java file to a new location.

I have two problems:

1. since the three files have the same name, a warning appears whether to overwrite or not
2. I am able to save the three files in the same folder which I don't want. I want to create three similar folders (like `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`) in a desired location and save the newly created java.

Does anyone know what to do?

```
for /r . %G% in (*.class) do jad -s .java -af -d "%my_desired_filelocation%" "%G%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started...

```
@echo off
for /R %%G in (*.class) do (
    echo %my_desired_filelocation%\%%~pG
    rem md "%my_desired_filelocation%\%%~pG"
    rem jad -s .java -af -d "%my_desired_filelocation%\%%~pG" "%%~fG"
)
```

Comment: but this is not working as expected...
if the path is 
" C:\Users\Shyam\desktop\test1 "
and my desired location is 
" C:\Users\shyam\Desktop\test2 "
the above code is giving the following location
" C:\Users\shyam\Desktop\test2\Users\Shyam\desktop\test1"